# how can i compare a string input from a jtextfield (.getText()) with another String[] Array? +few conditions

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I need to do say that if the input(text field) is empty when the button is clikced then print a message. and if one of the characters in the input doesn't equal to one of the elements in 'legal' list then print another error message. if all the characters in the input are fine then add them to some list and print a message msg

```
    String[] legal={"a", "b", "c", "d" ,"e" ,"f" ,"g" ,"h" ,"i" ,"j" ,"k" ,"l" ,"m" 
 ,"n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","w","x","y","z","-","_"}; 

    if(e.getSource() == add){

        if (txt.getText().equals("")){

            content.removeAll();
            content.add(empty);           
            content.revalidate();

        }  
        String[] splited = txt.getText().toLowerCase().split("");
        for (int t=0;t<splited.length;t++) {
            for (int u=0;u<legal.length;u++){
                if(splited[t] != legal[u]){

                    content.removeAll();
                    content.add(check);
                    content.revalidate();
                }
                else if(splited[t].equals( legal[u])){

                    content.removeAll();
                    list.add(txt.getText());
                    content.add(msg);
                    content.revalidate();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are seeing, and how do your expected results differ from your actual results?

Comment: What's problem with your code? Also, why are you implementing this using strings? Make `legal` a `char[]` and use `.charAt()` to loop over `txt`.

Comment: You could quite easily use a regular expression for this, by the way. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String) Also note that you do not need to `split("")` to access individual characters, you can use `charAt()` or, if you must, `toCharArray()`.

Comment: if i change legal list from String to char, it gives me an error: Incompatible Types:
Required:char
Found: Java.lang.String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take the UI out of the equation for moment.

To test if a `String` is empty, you have a number of options, based on what you consider an empty `String` to be, for example...

```
if (text == null || text.trim().isEmpty()) {...}
```

Will catch occurrences where the `String` value is `null` or is of `0` length when the leading and trailing spaces are removed.

To check if a `String` contains a valid set of characters, it would be much simpler to use the regular expression functionality supplied by the API, for example...

```
if (text.matches("[a-z\\-_]+")) {
    System.out.println("Matches");
}
```

Will match all characters between `a` and `z` and the `_`, `-` characters.  This means that the `String` must be in lower case ;)

Comment: Always use regex if you get the chance :]

Comment: i just edited my code, and seems to work perfectly.
Thank you very much my friend.

Comment: @KhalifaBader That makes a nice change :P

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is here:

```
if(splited[t] != legal[u]){
```

You cannot use `==` and `!=` to compare strings. Instead you would have to check:

```
if(!splited[t].equals(legal[u])){
```

Furthermore, your logic could be simplified to just one case and an else:

```
if(splited[t].equals(legal[u])){
    // it is legal
} else {
    // it is not legal 
}
```

That said, there are much simpler ways to do this. For example, you can access a character directly without the use of `split("")` by using [`String.charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29). You can also directly convert a `String` to a `char[]` by using [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

However, you have a general overuse of `String` (e.g. your `String[]` could really be a `char[]`).

You can also quite easily use a regular expression without all these `String` arrays and splitting, see [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), for example:

```
if (txt.matches("[a-zA-Z_-]+")) { 
    // string is legal
} else {
    // string is not legal
}
```

Comment: I made those changes and it worked, i didn't know that if(splited[t] != legal[u]){  is the problem. 
I used the matches method though, looks simpler and neater.
Thanks for the effort.